# How to sort aggregations where the keys have international characters?

Tags: elasticsearch, unicode, unicode-string, elasticsearch-aggregation

Given a database which contains a list of people, where they live, and their wealth/income/tax level, I've given my Elasticsearch 5.6.2 this mapping:

```
mappings => {
    person => {
        properties => {
            name => {
                type   => 'text',
                fields => {
                    raw => {
                        type => 'keyword',
                    },
                },
            },

            county => {
                type   => 'text',
                fields => {
                    raw => {
                        type => 'keyword',
                    },
                },
            },

            community_name => {
                type   => 'text',
                fields => {
                    raw => {
                        type => 'keyword',
                    },
                },
            },

            wealth => {
                type => 'long',
            },

            income => {
                type => 'long',
            },

            tax => {
                type => 'long',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

One county can have several communities, and I want to do an aggregation that creates an overview of the average wealth/income/tax for each of the counties and for each each county's communities.

This seems to work:

```
aggs => {
    counties => {
        terms => {
            field => 'county.raw',
            size  => 100,
            order => { _term => 'asc' },
        },

        aggs => {
            communities => {
                terms => {
                    field => 'community_name.raw',
                    size  => 1_000,
                    order => { _term => 'asc' },
                },

                aggs => {
                    avg_wealth => {
                        avg => {
                            field => 'wealth',
                        },
                    },

                    avg_income => {
                        avg => {
                            field => 'income',
                        },
                    },

                    avg_tax => {
                        avg => {
                            field => 'tax',
                        },
                    },
                },

            },

            avg_wealth => {
                avg => {
                    field => 'wealth',
                },
            },

            avg_income => {
                avg => {
                    field => 'income',
                },
            },

            avg_tax => {
                avg => {
                    field => 'tax',
                },
            },

        },

    },
},
```

However, the "county" and "community_name" aren't sorted correctly because some of them have Norwegian characters in them, meaning that ES sorts "Ål" before "Øvre Eiker", which is wrong.

How can I achieve correct Norwegian sorting?

**EDIT:** I tried changing the "community_name" field to use "icu_collation_keyword" instead of "keyword":

```
community_name => {
    type   => 'text',
    fields => {
        raw => {
            type     => 'icu_collation_keyword',
            index    => 'false',
            language => 'nb',
        },
    },
},
```

But this results in garbled output:

```
Akershus - 276855 - 229202 - 80131
    ᦥ免⡠႐໠  - 314430 - 243684 - 87105
    ↘卑◥猔᠈〇㠖 - 202339 - 225665 - 78186
    ⚞乀⃠᷀　 - 306985 - 237405 - 83186
    ⦘卓敫တ倎瀤 - 218060 - 218407 - 75602
    ⸳䄓†怜〨 - 271174 - 216843 - 75257
```

Comment: You should give a shot at the [ICU collation keyword field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.6/analysis-icu-collation-keyword-field.html)

Comment: Not saying this is the correct solution, but have you considered using this filter to attempt to simplify the sort ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score 0):

If the field on which you want to do aggregation (`community_name` in your example) always has only one value, then I think you might try the following approach, which is an extension of where you got so far.

Basically, you can add **another sub-aggregation on the original, non-garbled value**, and fetch it on the client side for display.

I will show it on a simplified mapping:

```
PUT /icu_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "community": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "norwegian": {
                            "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
                            "index": false,
                            "language": "nb"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "wealth": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We store community name as:

1. unchanged as `community`;
2. as `keyword` in `community.raw`;
3. as `icu_collation_keyword` in `community.norwegian`.

Then we put couple of documents (note: `community_name` has a string argument, not list of strings):

```
PUT /icu_index/my_type/2
{
    "community": "Ål",
    "wealth": 10000
}

PUT /icu_index/my_type/3
{
    "community": "Øvre Eiker",
    "wealth": 5000
}
```

Now we can do the aggregation:

```
POST /icu_index/my_type/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "communities": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "community.norwegian",
            "order": { 
                "_term": "asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "avg_wealth": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "wealth"
               }
            },
            "community_original": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "community.raw"
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

We are still sorting by `community.norwegian`, but we also add sub-aggregation on `community.raw`. Let's see the result:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "communities": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "⸳䃔楦၃৉瓅ᘂก捡㜂\u0000\u0001",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "community_original": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "Øvre Eiker",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "avg_wealth": {
                  "value": 5000
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "⸳䄏怠怜〨\u0000\u0000",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "community_original": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "Ål",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "avg_wealth": {
                  "value": 10000
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Now the buckets are sorted by ICU collation of community name. The first bucket with key `"⸳䃔楦၃৉瓅ᘂก捡㜂\u0000\u0001"` has its original value in `community_original.buckets[0].key`, which is `"Øvre Eiker"`.

NB: This hack will of course not work if `community_name` can be a list of values.

Hope this hack helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, "community_name" contain 400+ different values; they are actually names of municipalities within each county in Norway.

Comment: @toreau I mean 1 per document (which kind of makes sense, isn't it? A single address can only contain one town name, right?) Pls tell me if I get this wrong.